# How to store secret text or file using groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I have found how to store an Username/Password or SSH Username/PrivateKey using the groovy-based APIs for Jenkins.

https://gist.github.com/iocanel/9de5c976cc0bd5011653

```
domain = Domain.global()
store = Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList('com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider')[0].getStore()

priveteKey = new BasicSSHUserPrivateKey(
CredentialsScope.GLOBAL,
"jenkins-slave-key",
"root",
new BasicSSHUserPrivateKey.UsersPrivateKeySource(),
"",
""
)

usernameAndPassword = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl(
CredentialsScope.GLOBAL,
"jenkins-slave-password", "Jenkis Slave with Password Configuration",
"root",
"jenkins"
)

store.addCredentials(domain, priveteKey)
store.addCredentials(domain, usernameAndPassword)
```

There are more kinds of credentials that can be stored.  How do I do:

- Secret file
- Secret text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research, I found that the plain-credentials plugin implements the Secret Text and Secret File credentials.  I forked the gist above and added code for these two types (see the gist for the reqwuired imports).

https://gist.github.com/chrisvire/383a2c7b7cfb3f55df6a

```
secretText = new StringCredentialsImpl(
CredentialsScope.GLOBAL,
"secret-text",
"Secret Text Description",
Secret.fromString("some secret text goes here"))

file = new File("/path/to/some/file")
noFileItem = [ getName: { return "" } ] as FileItem

//FileCredentailsImpl can take a file from a do

secretFile = new FileCredentialsImpl(
  CredentialsScope.GLOBAL,
  "secret-file",
  "Secret File Description",
  noFileItem, // Don't use FileItem
  file.getName(),
  file.text
)

store.addCredentials(domain, secretText)
store.addCredentials(domain, secretFile)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error - "unable to resolve class StringCredentialsImpl"  any idea. I do have the plain Credential Plugin Installed.

Comment: @Dinesh import or fully qualify org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl

Answer (score 3):

Implementation using another FileCredentialsImpl constructor:

```
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.*;
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.FileCredentialsImpl;

def secret = '''Hi
there,
only
test'''

def secretBytes = SecretBytes.fromBytes(secret.getBytes())
def credentials = new FileCredentialsImpl(CredentialsScope.GLOBAL, 'my test file', 'description', 'file.txt', secretBytes)

SystemCredentialsProvider.instance.store.addCredentials(Domain.global(), credentials)
```

---

```
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.*;
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.FileCredentialsImpl;
import java.nio.file.*;

Path fileLocation = Paths.get("/path/to/some/file.txt");

def secretBytes = SecretBytes.fromBytes(Files.readAllBytes(fileLocation))
def credentials = new FileCredentialsImpl(CredentialsScope.GLOBAL, 'my test file', 'description', 'file.txt', secretBytes)

SystemCredentialsProvider.instance.store.addCredentials(Domain.global(), credentials)
```

Comment: Thanks for another implementation